# XMLHttpRequest fails asynchronously within phantomjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs

I have some rather straightforward code that fetches some data from a url using `XMLHttpRequest`... all the usual stuff, nothing too unusual, e.g.:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() { ... };
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.timeout = 5000;
request.send();
```

When this code is run within a standard browser context, all is fine.  However, when invoked via phantomjs (called on a server running a node.js app), the very same code only seems to work when `request.open()` is specified as being synchronous (using `false` as the final arg).  So in phantomjs it works fine when using sync, but not async.  When run async, the request never completes successfully.

Is there an obvious reason why this would be the case, in the absence of some further example code?  Perhaps I've broken some rule of phantomjs and/or XMLHttpRequest.

Till now I've just accepted it, and ensured that the request is sync in phantomjs and async in the browser.  But now I'm trying to set up timeouts correctly, since I suspect that timeout isn't working as it should in sync mode, but may do in async mode, so I'm trying to make the call async even in phantomjs.  Even then, I have my concerns that timeout doesn't work as you might expect within phantomjs.

Any help specifically on the sync/async issue would be great, and even better would be some advice on getting timeout to work within phantomjs.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. I suspect you're exiting too early.

Comment: I'll see if I can get together a simplified example that exhibits the problem.  As for exiting too early, the thing is that when I run the same code (with async xhr) within Chrome, it runs just fine... doesn't exit too early then so I'm not sure why it would be exiting too early in phantomjs

Comment: Because you're never exiting Chrome. For PhantomJS, you must call `ph.exit()` otherwise the process just keeps running.

Comment: OK thanks, I see what you mean.  You could be onto something.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Artjom B., I've managed to track down what was going wrong.  It was probably a beginner's error to have not realized straight away that when stuff is happening asynchronously in an object creation call (`var x = new MyThing()` where the constructor for `MyThing` does lots of time-consuming stuff including `XMLHttpRequest` calls) then I need to deal with that in the code in which the object is created... otherwise I'm trying to reference the object before it's actually finished being created.

So here is what I do at the point of creating the object (in which the `XMLHttpRequest` calls are made):

```
var thing;

function myFunction() {

    // set up a flag and flag-setting callback function
    var fin = false;
    function setFlag () {
        fin = true;
    }

    // this is what takes time, and with async XMLHttpRequest calls
    // pass the callback function, which is run in the object constructor as the final step
    thing = new MyThing(setFlag); 

    // keep checking if the MyThing code has completed (based on 'fin' flag), then continue with doTheRest() when it has
    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (fin) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            doTheRest();
        }
    }, 50);

}
```

Then the function `doTheRest()` that starts once the above is complete...

```
function doTheRest() {

    // do some processing to generate some stuff required to be rendered on the page, using the 'thing' object created before...
    var stuff = doSomeProcessing(thing);

    if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom(stuff);
    }
}
```

The `window.callPhantom()` call is at the heart of what is needed to make the code work asynchronously, and is described [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).  It is paired with a `page.onCallback` callback function, which you define before you run the `page.evaluate()` function which is what actually kicks off the main code (above) in the first place:

```
page.onCallback = function(svg) {
    // finally we've got the data we need, and can use it...
    // and only in the function below do we ever call phantom.exit(), so we have ensured that we don't exit phantomjs before we have got and used the data 
    renderSVG(svg);
};

page.open('about:blank', function (status) {
        page.evaluate(myFunction);
    }
});
```

See also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/MKSbZHRp5Bg) for a bit more on the subject.

Hope this helps someone else one day, even the person who downvoted my original question.